# Are there any additional tasks I should choose when installing VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, default

I am installing VS Code for the first time on my windows based laptop.  During the install process, a pop-up asks to select additional tools.  By default, "Register code as an editor for supported file types" and "Add to PATH" are selected.  Do I need to select these options or any of the others provided?

[installation pop up screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCMiV.png)

Comment: You need to check all features you actually want to have and use.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of these features. I'm trying to learn the basics of vs code for now.  Can I install it without any of the additional features since I'm a beginning user?

Comment: You can install it however you want. If you don't know what the options do, just keep them as they are.

Comment: Since it's "additional features", it's nice-to-have but not required. Also, you can probably do those steps manually yourself later.